# Property of an Object VS Calling function

Tags: javascript, oop

so I'm trying to figure out different ways to declare functions... and what is the best method for low memory usage...

the way I've been doing it is method #4 which I'm guessing is ATROCIOUS. I basically make bunch of different "`function XYZ(){ //stuff }`" and been calling it to execute the actions... more or less a way to housekeep all the code and have it organized... not because of performance, memory, or any technical related reason... Can anyone please pitch in and explain which method is best? (or if you have your own method please post) and why?

```
//method 1
var sayHey = new Object();
    sayHey.derp = 'derp';
    sayHey.herp = function(){
        alert('herp');
    };

//side question: would this.derp = 'derp' be the same as sayHey.derp? if so, would it be better to use this rather than sayHey?


//method 2
var sayHey2 = function() {
    return {
        derp : 'derp',
        herp : function(){
            alert('herp');
        }
    }
}();

//method 3
var sayHey3 = {
    derp: 'derp',
    herp: function(){
        alert('herp');
    }
};

//method 4
var derp = 'derp';
function herp(){
    alert('herp');
}
```

Comment: *"...the way I've been doing it is method #5..."* There is no method 5 in your question.

Comment: sorry... fixed. I meant method 4

Comment: fyi.. in JavaScript, all *functions* are **objects**. So you can create objects and it can have property values that are functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Methods 1 and 3* are identical. Just different ways of creating an object.
- *side question:* `this.derp` is `"derp"` if you invoked the method direclty from the object. In other words, if you do `this.herp()`, then `this` in the `herp()` function will be your  `sayHey` object.
- *Method 2* is also the same, except there's an unnecessary function call that makes no particular use of the variable scope created. You could make `derp` a local variable inside the function instead of a property on the object, so that it can only be accessed via the `herp()` method. This provides some protection of the variable.
- *Method 4* is making a local function, so you're not getting it directly on your object. There are different use cases for each.

Comment: Sorry if this is not the right place to ask, but...
For method 2. how would I utilize the variable scope? by having "var x = 0' and calling it after return? 

and for Method 1/3, is it bad to have "big" objects with lots of variables, functions attached to it (I guess this is when variable scopes come in to play)? or is it better to have different clusters of objects... (or is that defeating the purpose of objects in general)

Thank you so much

Comment: @HarrisonSeo: For Method 2, you would remove `derp:"derp",` from the object being returned, and do `var derp = "derp";` *above* the returned object, but still inside the immediately invoked function. Then inside the `herp()` method, you'd do `alert(derp);`, and it would read that variable. This is because functions create what's called a closure. In other words, they are permanently bound to their lexical scope, so when the function is returned with the object, it still references its original variables. ...more to come...

Comment: @HarrisonSeo: WRT Method 1/3, no it's not bad. It just depends on your particular needs. Objects are collections of data, and so sometimes it makes sense to have an object that has both data and functions on it. If you're creating several of these objects that all have the same methods, then you can use prototypal inheritance so that you're not creating the same functions over and over.

Comment: ...but don't worry too terribly much about some of these performance considerations. Different JavaScript implementations always have very different ways of optimizing different things, so what is more efficient in one implementation may not be in another.

Comment: Thank you so much... I've been just using jQuery + procedural programming with localized functions. With this, although I still do not fully understand its potential (maybe because I never needed OOP for scripts that I wrote) I can have a much better understanding. Thank you!